# OrientDB and OLAP?

Tags: orientdb, olap-cube, analytical

What is the status of OrientDB support for higher level structures such as cube cells, dimensions, OLAP/BI in general? Analytical functions/window functions? These are common in high-end databases (Oracle, MSSQL, Postgres). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same and http://cgnal.com/blog/how-to-reduce-the-gap-between-oltp-and-olap-graph-solutions-with-spark-tinkerpop/ suggest that it is an OLAP DB.

> Titan, OrientDB, Neo4j are examples of OLTP tools